# Fails to install andgram (android instagram)

Tags: android, import

I'm trying to install and test the andgram application available at https://github.com/markchang/android-instagram.git

But, some layout files show the following message and Eclipse doesn't generate the R.java file:

NOTE: This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.

Couldn't resolve resource @style/ActionBar

I thought it was the SDK version, but I have the version 8 installed and it doesn't solve the problem.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The library you are trying use depends on the [android-actionbar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) library.  Have you downloaded that library and added it as a library project to your project?

Edit:

FYI, The actionbar library it depends on is outdated (2+ years).

Comment: -1 the ActionBar is already integrated in the Android framework(for API 11+).

Comment: Did you even look at the source code he said he is including? The code does not use the standard actionbar.

Comment: I was able to download both packages and compile cleanly with a target API 8

Comment: Oh. I just saw that it used the ActionBar keyword... Who still uses any other ActionBar implementation than ABS?! sorry for the down vote, could you edit your answer, so I could remove it?(can't do it now, it's locked)

Comment: Yeah, I thought that at first too, but when I clicked over to git I saw the old library in the imports.  Edited answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you again, Ahmad. Now, it works perfectly even when I set the target to API 8. The project.properties looks like this:                   target=android-8
android.library.reference.1=../../../../../Desktop/android-actionbar/actionbar

Answer (score 0):

You have change your build target to at least API 11 in order to support the ActionBar.

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot, Ahmad!

Comment: I'm sorry. I was wrong. The problem is still there! Do you have any other suggestion?